# Merging a single git commit (From a separate branch) into multiple separate Pull Requests

Tags: git, pull-request

I came across a... shall we say...interesting scenario with git and my code base this week, I had a piece of logic that I wrote that would be used by 10 future features that I knew I would be soon to implement.

The piece of logic being an ABTest for these future features.

I approached it by implementing the ABTest first and creating a Pull request. My PR was crtiqued because the PR itself didn't actually do anything.

So I could either justify its existence for future usage, or just keep the branch/commit and close the PR without merging it... and therefore merge the commit into each future feature PR.

Is the latter option the recommended approach for best practices?

I personally don't think its a big deal and the original PR should be mergeable but the original reviewer is away on leave and unable to discuss... so I'm considering the alternative option...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are possible: it boils down to a communication problem.

But if you cannot deliver a feature without an ABTest, delivering each one with said ABTest  remains the more coherent approach.
If that ABTest is the same for all feature, delivering it with the first feature allows it to be reused by the next 9 feature PRs.